# How to propely design a combination of many sub-classes?

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

**I have a parent class** - `Product`

```
public abstract class Product {}
```

**And 3 sub-classes which extends it:**

1. `public class Vinyl extends Product {}`
2. `public class Book extends Product {}`
3. `public class Video extends Product {}`

All sub-classes override the `preview()` method with their specific implementation.
Now, I have a new design demand: I need to define a **combo** item of `vinyl` & `book` which also has a `preview()` method (which is a **combination** of vinyl & book). In the instructions it says I can create Interface\ class field member or any implementation I want to support it, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Is the new design should also be implemented with `inheritance` or should I change the current design?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Or are you asking for someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: I'm not asking for anyone making me homework, on the contrary, I want to become wiser with new design\style which I can't see because I got stuck...
I'm just asking for an idea - leave me the implementation :)

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: This is a design question and as such there are multiple correct answers. By giving us only 4 classes and no details about them (except for the extends) you're making it harder for us to give a good answer. Tell us what defines a Product in your domain, and what a Vinyl/Book are in concrete.

Comment: It's easy to say "Composition over Inheritance" and it's usually true, applying it can be a little harder and with only this much information we can't really tell the best option

Comment: A vinylBook sounds like an instance of a Book object unless you provide more details

Comment: @Nimrod Now that you have clarified your intent, I have provided you an answer. The solution is to use the `Composite` pattern.

Comment: @PedroDavid - Basically, I have a digital store with 3 products (vinyl, video and books) and I need to implement a preview method validation for each of the products. because of the strong relation between the products types - I thought the most suitable implementation would be with `inheritance`.

I did this part and now I have a new design task to define a combo product.

Comment: So what defines a Product in fact Is a preview method. Fantastic. For sure you will use Inheritance for that, every single Product will have a preview(). The thing now is, how to you define a Vinyl and a Book and a VinylBoock. They all need a Preview() because They're all products, but probably Vinyl has some set of "Properties" as well as Book. These Properties should be well defined (maybe another class or interface) and trough Composition you should give Vinyl the "VinylProperties", Book the "BookProperties" and VinylBook both.

Comment: @Nimrod Do take a look at my answer and let me know if it helps or please respond with additional clarifications :)

Comment: @cking - perfect :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the new design should also be implemented with inheritance or should I change the current design?

The new design can be implemented purely with inheritance. But the real problem with this would be that you would have way too many subclasses. You could easily create a new subclass of `Product` called `VinylBook` and be done with it. But what happens when you have to introduce another combination, say `VinylVideo`. You would have to create a new subclass for this as well and so on.

The solution is to use inheritance and composition together. The Composite pattern would be a good fit for this problem. According to wikipedia :

> The composite pattern describes that a group of objects is to be treated in the same way as a single instance of an object. Implementing the composite pattern lets clients treat individual objects and compositions uniformly.

Let's start by defining a `CompositeProduct`

```
public class CompositeProduct` extends Product {
     private List<Product> products;

     public CompositeProduct(List<Product> products) { this.products = products }

     public String preview() {
          String previewText = "";
          for(Product product : products) { previewText+=product.preview(); }
          return preview;

     }
}
```

You now have composite product that behaves as if it is one single product allowing you to create combo products on the fly without the need to create a new subclass for each combo.

An example of how you can create products on the fly :

```
Book book = new Book();
Vinyl vinyl = new Vinyl();
List<Product> products = new List<>();
products.add(book);
products.add(vinyl);
CompositeProduct vinylBook = new CompositeProduct(products);
```

You can also take a look at the Decorator pattern if you are looking at adding additional behavior to your products on the fly.

Comment: It's a good alternative, but without more information this seems a way to avoid a design problem instead a way to improve the design.

Comment: @PedroDavid I don't completely follow what you mean.

Comment: "Smashing" products together is easy, now smashing them with the corresponding logic is way harder than what you've just shown. But to be honest that is the best answer the question could have with the details supplied

Comment: @PedroDavid The way I see it, there are only limited solutions to problems of this nature. Yes some details may change the approach but Composite pattern and Decorator pattern are solid options to get this done the right way..

Comment: I elaborated my issue with this solution in my answer and provided an alternative. I would appreciate your feedback

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give an alternative since I wasn't pleased by the other solution.(Don't get me wrong, it's simple and straight forward, also the Composite concept is a very good one to learn and the user also mentioned the Decorator pattern that it's really useful).

My problem with that solution is that you give the products (whichever they are) and then what can you do?

Let's imagine

```
public abstract class Product {
    abstract void preview();
}
```

Now your CompositeProduct is so generic that can only implement something like this

```
void preview(){
    for(Product product : products) product.preview();
}
```

And I bet that's not what you want.

My alternative is using Composition through interfaces. I can't tell much with more detail on the Domain so I will give a simple example.

What is a Book? Let's imagine something Readable.

```
public interface Readable { void read(); }

public class Book extends Product implements Readable {}
```

What is a Vinyl? Showable

```
public interface Showable { void show(); }

public class Vinyl extends Product implements Showable {}
```

Now BookVinyl would simply be

```
public class BookVinyl extends Product implements Readable, Showable { }
```

What will this give you? Well, now BookVinyl can be read, just like a book, and show, just like a Vinyl. And the preview? It can show and then read or whatever.

Comment: Number of classes can be daunting indeed. But when someone creates a VinylAudio it's not supposed to just be a Vynil + Audio, it should have it's own logic and for that you would need a different class anyway. Your answer is pretty clean and really generic, but in my opinion too generic. That said with the information the only one that can take a conclusion about the better option is the one that asked the question.

Comment: The real problem with this solution is the number of subclasses that need to be created for every new combination. With just 3 product types, you can have so many different combiniations (VinylBook, VinylVideo, Book, Video and Vinyl). Introduce another product type and you end up with even more classes (Audio, VinylAudio, AudioBook, VinylAudioBook). Not to mention the addition of another interface called Listenable.